# Help !!! 2007 Honda Accord 2.2 diesel not starting intermittently

Tags: engine, honda, starting, diagnostics, electrical

my Honda Accord has developed an issue where by sometimes it fails to start when the key is turned, it will turn over but not start, the green key light stays Stays flashing on the dash, does this mean the immobiliser system did not read the key? I brought it to a main dealer and thankfully the issue happened on them but they could not establish a connection and communicate with the ECU whenever green key was flashing, Strangely after numerous attempts putting the key into the ignition trying to start And whenever it accepted the key and allowed the car to start the diagnostic would communicate with the ECU and then scan would say no immobiliser faults?? There is a fault code in the log P0602,
Has anyone seen this type of issue before, the technician has never seen where they can't communcate with the key not reading, as they program new keys in that condition.where do I start replacing stuff??

Comment: Hi Guys, Just adding update info for this issue, the mechanic got it sorted, he had to replace the main engine ECU and recode it into the car. Problem gone for now at least.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED FIXED FIXED Finally after tearing my car to pieces over the last four months I have finally fixed it,  intermittently not starting, green flashing key, no engine light when it won't start, no fault codes, checked keys, chips, fuses, relays, wiring loom, key reader, ignition barrel and on and on and on.
FINALLY bought an ecu of ebay that matched the number of mine of ebay for £35, plugged it in, garage plugged in a Snap on diagnostic tool to tell the car it had a new e u fitted, in the key/immobiliser section,, it paired with the 2and hand ecu and BOOOOM FIXED : )))), the hours I spent on forums trying to find a solution. : )